# Why is my Android socketserver triggering a socket error 10061 in my client

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, serversocket

I'n using Kotlin coroutines to setup a Java serversocket in Android studio 4.0 Beta 5. I'm running in the emulator on Windows 10. When my very reliable c language socket client attempts to connect using 127.0.0.1 as the IP it receives error 10061. The same client program  has worked well for many years with a Java Swing socketserver.

Google give the following explanation for error 10061:

> 10061 is a Connection Refused error sent to you by the server. You could not make a 
>   connection because the target machine actively refused it. The most common cause is a
>   misconfigured server, full server, or incorrect Port specified by the client.

Here's my code snippet

```
    int myPort = 8080;         
    String localIP = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
    ServerSocket srv = new ServerSocket();
    String hostname = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
    srv.bind(new InetSocketAddress(hostname,myPort));
    srv.setSoTimeout(socketAcceptTimeOut);    //This sets the timeout on the accept
    Socket cli = srv.accept();
```

I used the server bind based on another stackoverflow answer but it did't help when I removed it. In any case I believe the serversocket is listening at 127.0.0.1. I'm using port 8080 but I've tried a few others.

On the Android side the srv.accept is just timing out.

What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: You don't need the explicit `bind()`, just use the `ServerSocket` constructor that takes a port as input: `ServerSocket srv = new ServerSocket(myPort);` That will bind the server to all local IPs.  If you want to bind to a specific IP, `ServerSocket` has a constructor for that, too: `ServerSocket srv = new ServerSocket(myPort, 0, InetAddress.getByName(desiredIP));` Also, does your Android app have the `android.permission.INTERNET` permission enabled?

Comment: I just ran my app on my phone.  I changed the following line to use my phone's real localIP:
    `srv.bind(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.1.14",myPort));`
now the "accept" works. 
So the code seems to be okay and it's something to do with netorking in the emulator.